# Javascript alert box and confirmation after

Tags: php, javascript

I want to create a javascript for checking value of textbox so if the textbox blank, it won't proceed to next page. AND after checking (if all condition is true) it will return the result of textbox.

I've created this javascript:

```
function cekdata(myform)
{
    var id = document.myform.clientid.value;
        var nama = document.myform.nama.value;
        var divisi = document.myform.divisi.value;
        var way = document.getElementById('twoway').value;
        var ori = document.myform.lokasi.value;
        var desti = document.myform.tujuan.value;
        var ket = document.myform.keterangan.value;
        var tpergi = document.myform.tglb.value;
        var jpergi = document.myform.jamb.value;
        var mpergi = document.myform.menitb.value;
        var pegi = tpergi+', '+jpergi+':'+mpergi;
        var tplg = document.myform.tglp.value;
        var jplg = document.myform.jamp.value;
        var mplg = document.myform.menitp.value;
        var plg = tplg+', '+jplg+':'+mplg;
  if (document.myform.clientid.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Your ID");
    myform.clientid.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.nama.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Passenger Name");
    myform.nama.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.lokasi.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Origin Location");
    myform.lokasi.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.tujuan.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Your Destination");
    myform.tujuan.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.tglb.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Departure Date");
    myform.tglb.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.novehicle.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Vehicle Number");
    myform.novehicle.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (document.myform.driverid.value == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Driver ID");
    myform.driverid.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if(document.getElementById('twoway').checked)
  {
      if (document.myform.tglp.value == "")
      {
        alert("Please Fill Return Date");
        myform.tglp.focus();
        return false;
      }
      else
      if (document.myform.tglb.value > document.myform.tglp.value)
      {
        alert("Return date must bigger than departure date");
        myform.tglp.focus();
        return false;
      }
  }
  else
  {
        var a = window.confirm("CONFIRMATION :\nID : " +id+"\nName : "+nama+"\nDivision : "+divisi+"\nOne Way : "+way+"\nOrigin : "+ori+"\nDestination : "+desti+"\nNotes : "+ket+"\nDeparture : "+pegi+"\nArrived :"+plg);
        if (a==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
  }
}
```

And I called this function like this:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return cekdata(this);" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
```

But what I got is the confirm box never show up, and it returns true (and go to next page). So, how to change this condition so my confirmation box showed up first, then after click OK, it go to next page, and if CANCEL, do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*Just make slight changes in your javascript just passevent on form submit*


<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onClick="return cekdata(this,event);" />
```

and when your textbox is empty or null write event.preventDefault() instead of return false;

```
function cekdata(myform,evt)
{
var id = document.myform.clientid.value;
    var nama = document.myform.nama.value;
    var divisi = document.myform.divisi.value;
    var way = document.getElementById('twoway').value;
    var ori = document.myform.lokasi.value;
    var desti = document.myform.tujuan.value;
    var ket = document.myform.keterangan.value;
    var tpergi = document.myform.tglb.value;
    var jpergi = document.myform.jamb.value;
    var mpergi = document.myform.menitb.value;
    var pegi = tpergi+', '+jpergi+':'+mpergi;
    var tplg = document.myform.tglp.value;
    var jplg = document.myform.jamp.value;
    var mplg = document.myform.menitp.value;
    var plg = tplg+', '+jplg+':'+mplg;
if (document.myform.clientid.value == "")
{
alert("Please Fill Your ID");
myform.clientid.focus();
```

**evt.preventDefault();**
    }

Comment: it works right now after I remove the event.prevent and get the method in form tag... thanks for Your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would better suggest you to place that **cekdata(this)** in your **submit tag** rather than **form tag**. Like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onClick="return cekdata();" />
```

And also when you have done this

```
var id = document.myform.clientid.value;
```

Then why you are using again the same

```
if (document.myform.clientid.value == "")
```

Better use

```
var id = document.myform.clientid;

if (id.value == "")
{
   alert("Please Fill Your ID");
   id.focus();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: well, I'm adding new function to my JS, that's why it written like that. But nothing happened, its just do same thing, go to next page without showing the confirmation first

Comment: i would suggest you to change the name of passed argument in js function i.e. "myform", as it same as of form name.

Comment: it is... the validation is work... just the confirmation not work.. but after changing my code like nitin-sharma do, without the vent..prevent it works normally.. thanks for any answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove your **last** else part and paste below lines at the end of your javascript function.

Remove below lines :

```
var a = window.confirm("CONFIRMATION :\nID : " +id+"\nName : "+nama+"\nDivision : "+divisi+"\nOne Way : "+way+"\nOrigin : "+ori+"\nDestination : "+desti+"\nNotes : "+ket+"\nDeparture : "+pegi+"\nArrived :"+plg);
```

instead use this,

```
var a = window.confirm("Are you sure?");

if (a==true)
{
     return true;
}
else
{
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Try my update. If any of the value may be miss from your last var a = ... line.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I'm using nitin-sharma method without event.prevent, it works now... thanks for any answer..

Answer (score 0):

Changing code like this:

```
function cekdata(myform)
{
    var id = document.myform.clientid.value;
    var nama = document.myform.nama.value;
    var divisi = document.myform.divisi.value;
    var way = document.getElementById('twoway').value;
    var ori = document.myform.lokasi.value;
    var desti = document.myform.tujuan.value;
    var ket = document.myform.keterangan.value;
    var tpergi = document.myform.tglb.value;
    var jpergi = document.myform.jamb.value;
    var mpergi = document.myform.menitb.value;
    var pegi = tpergi+', '+jpergi+':'+mpergi;
    var tplg = document.myform.tglp.value;
    var jplg = document.myform.jamp.value;
    var mplg = document.myform.menitp.value;
    var plg = tplg+', '+jplg+':'+mplg;
  if (id == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Your ID");
    myform.clientid.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (nama == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Passenger Name");
    myform.nama.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (ori == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Origin Location");
    myform.lokasi.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (desti == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Your Destination");
    myform.tujuan.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if (tpergi == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill Departure Date");
    myform.tglb.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
  if(document.getElementById('twoway').checked)
  {
      if (tplg == "")
      {
        alert("Please Fill Return Date");
        myform.tglp.focus();
        return false;
      }
      else
      if (tpergi > tplg)
      {
        alert("Return date must bigger than departure date");
        myform.tglp.focus();
        return false;
      }
  }
  else
  {
        var a = window.confirm("CONFIRMATION :\nID : " +id+"\nName : "+nama+"\nDivision : "+divisi+"\nOne Way : "+way+"\nOrigin : "+ori+"\nDestination : "+desti+"\nNotes : "+ket+"\nDeparture : "+pegi+"\nArrived :"+plg);
        if (a==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
  }
}
```

then it works...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Jquery insead of Javascript.

Here is the short & sweet code I have made just for you, feel free to use it!

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(){
     var id = $('#id').val();
     var dataString = 'id='+ id;
     if(id==''){
        alert("Please Fill Your ID");
        $('#id').focus();
        return false;  
         }
     else if(confirm("Are you sure? Your id = "+id))
        {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajxRegistration.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(e)
           {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
           }
     });
      return false;
    }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for sharing... I'll try it later since my client need it fast, I will use my old JS... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
    return true;
 else
    return false;
```